# No light in material preview and render

Tags: rendering, light

My objects just don't get any light in render. And they look like empty png in render. It happened one day, I was working in Blender 2.8. Than I installed 2.9 and the problem was gone for some time. Now it happen again. I`m not very experienced user, maybe I just pressed the wrong button somewhere.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is your graphics card an AMD gpu?

Comment: Yes. Is that a problem?

Comment: The latest drivers have an issue.  If you roll back to the previous version it should resolve.

Comment: Yeah, that helped. Thank you so much

Comment: It's not working with Nvidia Drivers as well

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did: tick "High Quality Normals" in the Render Properties[image: Fix]