# Viewport "material preview" all gray

Tags: 3d-view

I am looking to get some help from you all. I recently (today) encountered an issue where the material preview in viewport does not seem to work. All the materials come out gray. I am not sure what is happening and any help would be greatly appreciated[image]. I attached an image for the issue I have.

Thanks!

Comment: Yet another AMD GPU?

Comment: Let me guess.... you have an AMD GPU?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204476/no-light-in-material-preview-and-render?noredirect=1#comment344118_204476

Comment: Thanks all, yes I have an AMD GPU. Which driver should I downgrade to?