# Wireframe and Texture Preview No Longer Working

Tags: texturing, 3d-view, error, wireframe

Before this morning, I used to be able to:

1. See the image textures of my meshes in Material Preview and Rendered preview, both in Eevee and Workbench engines.
2. See the image textures of my meshes as I render them, in said engines
3. See the wireframe edges within the mesh in 3D viewport when not in edit mode
4. Be able to select meshes by clicking them in the 3D viewport

Now, I cannot do any of those things said above. Anytime I go to wireframe or Material Preview, all meshes are a dark grey colour like the background, and on some meshes, the outline does not even appear:

Wireframe Mode
[image: Wireframe Mode]

Material Preview Mode
[image: Material Preview Mode]

On old .blend files however, the image textures work in Workbench engine, but not for new files.

What's the problem?

Here are my susceptible settings:
-The "Wireframe" slider in "Viewport Overlays" is already set to 1.000, as it was before,
-The materials that I initially set image texture of were not modified at all, and Alpha is at 1.000, like before
-"Display As" in Object Properties is already set at Textured.

Because I updated my AMD Radeon graphics drivers to the latest version (20.11.2) just last night, I suspect that that was the problem, and so I updated Blender as well from 2.90 to 2.91 (latest build). Still didn't fix the problem.

What's the issue? Please help, because this is making it impossible to do my work.

Specs:

GPU: AMD Radeon R9 380 Series

CPU: AMD FX-6300 6-core Processor

Blender versions: 2.90 and 2.91

RAM: 8.00 GB

OS: Windows 10, 64 bit

Comment: AMD, AMD, AMD... downgrade to the drivers you had yesterday,

Comment: @susu The reason I upgraded them was because having that previous build was causing my games to randomly crash. Updating them fixed that problem but made this one. Please be more helpful.

Comment: AMD has issues with the drivers. The only advice I can give is not to use that brand... probably not the advice you want.

Comment: If you want more information, please search through the questions with the exact same problem as yours that popped since the now infamous update. see https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/204496/86891